# Using scikit learn's GaussianNB with nltk doesn't work

Tags: python, scikit-learn, nltk

I am trying to use nltk's wrapper for scikit-learn's classifiers. I use this code to train the classifier:

```
classifier = SklearnClassifier(GaussianNB())
classifier.train(self.training_set)
```

Where `training_set` looks like

```
[({'name':'Alpha Hotel', 'clicks':765, 'zip_code':75025},'no bookings')]
```

The error I am getting is

> TypeError: A sparse matrix was passed, but dense data is required. Use
>   X.toarray() to convert to a dense numpy array.

I don't know how to convert to a dense array, especially since nltk's documentation for the `train` method requires `A list of (featureset, label) where each featureset is a dict mapping strings to either numbers, booleans or strings.`

Answer (score 0):

You have three features just two of them is in numerical format.You first should convert the 'name' feature to a number. If the name variable is categorical then you can encode it in a meaningful manner as described here:

http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/preprocessing.html#encoding-categorical-features

i think your labels also limited, so you can encode them too. The last step is really easy you just need to convert nltk format to numpy array format. just read each feature in a loop and then insert your desired features in X (features) and Y (labels):

http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.naive_bayes.GaussianNB.html

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it's was late, but maybe help other who get same problem(cz i got this problem yesterday).

> TypeError: A sparse matrix was passed, but dense data is required. Use X.toarray() to convert to a dense numpy array.

Like error said, it's need to convert to array so i just convert this to array as the error said

```
vector = vectorizer.transform(corpus).toarray()
```

So just add .toarray() solve this problem.
;)

when i switch to MultinomialNB or BernoulliNB, neither they didn't error. with or without toarray().

note: dont forget to convert to fit and transform your text to word representation(numeric values).